# Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR has drift: Is there an alternative?

Tags: android, accelerometer, gyroscope, magnetometer, sensor-fusion

I'm trying out Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR on Android. It is supposed to use magnetfieldsensor, accelerometer and gyroscope to provide accurate rotation at all times. However, I notice enormous drift occurring on Moto G 2nd. I wonder if this is a device specific issue, or that this occurs on a lot of phones (which I would assume, although I am familiar that Moto G 2nd is a problematic case with it's gyroscope).

Is there an alternative form of sensor fusion, which is drift free (using magnetsensor)? I have tried Google Cardboard's sensor fusion as well, but it uses bias estimation, so presumably not entirely drift free (as the magnetfieldsensor is not used at this time it seems), although still A LOT better than TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR.

Comment: An old Google Talk video on Sensor Fusion: https://youtu.be/C7JQ7Rpwn2k Also is the drift within the specs? `MUST have a variance no greater than 1e-7 rad^2 / s^2 per Hz (variance per Hz, or rad^2 /s). The variance is allowed to vary with the sampling rate, but must be constrained by this value. In other words, if you measure the variance of the gyro at 1 Hz sampling rate it should be no greater than 1e-7 rad^2/s^2.` http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/en//compatibility/android-cdd.pdf

Comment: As you are looking at this for AR which has long duration - that's probably why they added the HiFI Sensor feature `android.hardware.sensor.hifi_sensors`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.hitlabnz.sensor_fusion_demo has some handy alternatives I just found. I still have to test which fusion leads to most steady results. 
Source here: https://bitbucket.org/apacha/sensor-fusion-demo/src .

A lot of these also show drift; in particular the ones which use the gyro.

Answer (score 1):

## Platform/Hardware independent approach

1. Gyro will, by definition, *always* drift.
2. Magnetometer will, by definition, *lack* precision(*).
3. Accelerometer, as far as detecting device position goes, is of no value whatsoever.

A general approach consists in:

- listen to magnetometer changes notifications, with an amortization over time. This gives you **large** changes in device orientation changes.
- listen to gyroscopic changes notifications, with an amortization over time. This gives you **small** changes in device orientation changes.

---

(*) *In a cartesian physical world, the magnetometer should be enough, but in the earthling's universe, you need to compensate for the lack of magnetometer frequency of update, precision and external factors with the gyroscope, which provides immediate feedback.*